# Custom PHP App with a wordpress site

Tags: php

I have created a new 'page template' and (this is probably not the right way to do this, but this is the way I have got it working), and created a new page using that template.  Within the page template (PHP file) I have made, I have put lots of PHP which makes the page function, like it has a simple login an view information from a SQL table.

The problem is, I need to be able to send $_GET data to the page.  I can send POST fine, but not GET, and I dont know what the URL is.

For example, I would like to have clean URLs (that is what I have set wordpress to)

i.e.:

domain.com/teaching-portal/mygetdata

The name of the page template is teaching-portal, and I would like to get `mygetdata` into PHP.  But currently anything passed after teaching-portal results in a 404 page.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a page with the slug "teaching-portal", this plugin adds a rewrite rule for that page that allows one part to be added after it in the URL, what you refer to as "mygetdata". I've called it "lesson".

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom PHP app on teaching-portal page
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75991
 */

// Flush rewrite rules on plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse75991_activate');
function wpse75991_activate()
{
    wpse75991_add_rewrite_rule();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Flush rewrite rules on plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse75991_deactivate');
function wpse75991_deactivate()
{
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Add a custom rewrite rule for the teaching portal section
add_action('init', 'wpse75991_add_rewrite_rule');
function wpse75991_add_rewrite_rule()
{
    $pagename = 'teaching-portal'; // Slug
    add_rewrite_rule(
        $pagename.'/?([^/]*+)',
        'index.php?pagename='.$pagename.'&lesson=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

// Register the custom query var so WP recognizes it
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse75991_add_query_var');
function wpse75991_add_query_var($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'lesson';
    return $vars;
}
```

With this plugin activated you should be able to access the lesson variable in your page template. Here's a quick example:

```
$lesson = get_query_var('lesson');

if (empty($lesson))
{
    // Show all lessons
}
else
{
    // Show a single lesson
    var_dump($lesson);
}
```

Also see the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) in the codex.

Comment: Wow, very amazing.  That's really helpful, thank you so much.